# How is a device file created while interfacing with external device in linux environment?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am a newbie to linux kernel. While interfacing with the external device, I made the required changes in `bsp` file. The `bsp` file device name and `platform_driver` name should match in order to invoke `probe()`. I have heard that `probe` will check whether `h/w` exists and `probe()` will create device file (`/dev/rtc1`) for a new external device. I am not sure about the functionality of the `probe()`. Can someone explain me how device file is created in this context?Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`probe()` is a callback function that gets `called`, irrespective of `h/w` presence, when the `bus_match_driver()` routine returns `success`. The `probe` function is `called` when a `device` is installed that the `driver-core` thinks it should handle; the `probe` function should perform checks on the information passed to it about the device and decide whether the driver is really appropriate for that device. A `device file` is created either manually by `mknod` or automatically by `udev` and is not directly related to `probe` function. The book https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ (highly recommended) has all the details regarding creating a device node.

Comment: thanku..,then udev is the one who creates the device files(/dev/)at the time of booting??????